# Type-mismatch in between List.reduce and defined type

Tags: list, f#, type-mismatch

I'm trying to make a function array, which I'm using inside a List.reduce HOF.
I used to have a

```
let minimax = [| (min : int->int->int); max |]
```

which was working great, but now I want to get the max value of a list, so I thought:

```
let minimax = [|List.min; List.max|]
```

This, however, throws the following error:

Minimax.fs(175,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'minimax' has been inferred to have generic type
    val minimax : ('_a list -> '_a) [] when '_a : comparison
Either define 'minimax' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

I added a type annotation like this:

```
let minimax = [|(List.min:TreeOfPosition list -> TreeOfPosition); List.max|]
```

and it compiled. The problem now is with the List.reduce,

```
| BranchP(position, children) -> List.reduce (minimax.[minOrmax]) (List.map (loop (1 - minOrmax)) children)
```

Type mismatch. Expecting a     TreeOfPosition -> TreeOfPosition -> TreeOfPosition     but given a     TreeOfPosition list -> TreeOfPosition     The type 'TreeOfPosition' does not match the type 'TreeOfPosition list'

Thanks for any tip,

Pedro Dusso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `min` operates on two values but `List.min` operates on a list of values, so you can't just substitute one function for the other.  Since `List.min` is basically defined as `List.reduce min`, you can probably just get rid of the `List.reduce` and apply `minimax[minormax]` directly.  I can't see how that would be any better than your original solution with `min` and `max`, though... perhaps you could provide some additional context so it's clearer exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I missed some contextualization, but your tip (Since List.min is basically defined as List.reduce min) worked just fine! Thank you!